# Why does the following parameterized method not compile?

Tags: scala, parameterized

From the [Scala API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.Manifest), I got the following example, which does not compile;

```
scala> def arr[T] = new Array[T](0)
<console>:10: error: cannot find class manifest for element type T
       def arr[T] = new Array[T](0)
                    ^
```

I was wondering, why it does not compile (the Scala API does not explain the error) ?
Isn't it just a normal parameterized method ? Why does the compiler complain about it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the compiler error message says, you need a `Manifest` constraint.

```
scala> def arr[T : Manifest] = new Array[T](0)
arr: [T](implicit evidence$1: Manifest[T])Array[T]
```

Learn more about this [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_38.html). See [the paper](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/sids/cunei/Thu,%202009-10-01,%2013:54/arrays.pdf) for more in-depth information.

Comment: Oh, I see, this is an array-specific issue (e.g. `def createList[T] = List[T]()` works). Thank you, I will have a deeper look on it.

Comment: @JohnThreepwood, please consider accepting the answer if it solves your query.